# Horizontally scroll text on screen in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I've showed terms and condition page.

The text of agreement is large, so I've added scrollview, now it scrolls vertically. That has no problems.

But I expect the design to scroll the terms text horizontally too like viewpager.

My code is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#000000"  >
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Terms and Condition"
                android:layout_centerInParent= "true"
             />
        </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/RelativeLayout4"
        android:background="#123456">
            <ScrollView 
                android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                >
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lang_list_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/terms_condition">
                </TextView>
            </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#808080"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/page_indication"
            android:text="Pages:"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/done"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Agree "
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How to scroll the terms and condition text horizontally and indicate how many pages are there?

i expected design is [image]

Comment: you want scroll text manually or automatically??

Comment: You can have a look at this question in SO too http://stackoverflow.com/a/4027496/840520

Comment: i expect the text show full screen,if exceed the screen, it scroll horizontally. when user scroll manually .@AkashG

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) instead of a normal `ScrollView`. The implementation is similar

Comment: its showning single line text only. but it scrolling horizontally. But i expect the text show full screen,if exceed the screen, it scroll horizontally. @MartijinVanMierloo

Comment: `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` && `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`

Comment: i've changed the wrap_content to fill_parent. but still its so only single line horizontall scroll. my code is here,  http://pastie.org/4270246  @MartijnVanMierloo

Comment: You fill your TextView with a large amount of text. Because of the HorizontalScrollView, your TextView does not know when to go to the next line and will continue fill itself with text. This results in a large line of text from left to right which is scrollable. Is it a good idea to show you terms like this? Why not use a normal list? If you are certain that you want to implement it like your are now, you can tweak the heights and widths of the views. Or use a WebView to show text in.

Comment: i've added my expected design in my question, in that design, they expect horizontally move the terms and condition page. how to do like that? @MartijnVanMierloo

Comment: 1. Create an image.  2. Set minimum and maximum heights for your Views  3. Use WebView

Answer (score 1):

Check out this will scroll when user scrolls the text only when the text ecxeeds the width of the screen

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ho"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/lang_list_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/terms_condition">
            </TextView>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Implement this into your code.This will help you.
you can add android:singleLine="true" in textview to show text in single line.

Comment: i've changed but still show on single line horizontal. my code is here, http://pastie.org/4270264, pls check it. @AkashG

Comment: what r ur requirements??Do u want to show text in single Line or not??

Comment: Not in single line, i've expect multiple line, if exceed the layout height, it sroll horizontally @AkashG

Comment: horizontal scroll view is concerned with width and not with the height.

Comment: i expect like viewpageindicator.

Comment: Scroll it vertically rather than scrolling horizontally.r u getting what i mean to say??why u want to scroll horizontally if want to give it specific height??

Comment: that is what i mean to say.view pager fits best for ur requirements.

Comment: i've added my expected design in my question, in that design, they expect horizontally move the terms and condition page. how to do like that? @AkashG

Comment: as i told u view pager fits best for ur requirements

Comment: Check this : http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager/ , http://tamsler.blogspot.in/2011/10/android-viewpager-and-fragments.html , http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-example/.